# What does "filial inroads"mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> ...the second, that the pension bestowed upon her by a grateful country (and a Barnacle) would be freed from any little filial inroads, when her Henry should be married to the darling only child of a man in very easy circumstances.

The preceding passage is from Dickens' *Little Dorrit* Chapter 33.

What does the term "freed from  any little filial inroads" mean.?

Comment: Since this is just about extracting the meaning out of the individual words in context, you may want to try this over at [ell.se]

Comment: Anjan, please take care to format questions intelligibly and get the spelling right. Also: what research have you done? How could *inroads* apply here when paired with *filial*? (You did look those up, surely.)

Comment: It's a phrase, not a term. Do you know what *freed* means? Do you know what *inroads* means? Do you know what *filial*  means? What did the dictionary say about those?

Comment: Hello, Anjan.  Many reading Dickens find that they could do with a good dictionary beside them as they read.  Also, they need to get used to Dickens' fondness for expressing himself allusively.  She has acquired a 'pension'.  In Dickens, pensions are often the target of the hopes and needs of relatives, including Henry.  But he is to be married into family of financial substance and so will not need to make "filial" (look it up) inroads (i.e.) ask her for money.

Answer (score 1):

I shall assume you are familiar with some of the meanings of all or some of these words. For those who are not native English speakers the sentence poses some difficulties that are not easily resolvable by dictionary search alone. I therefore answer it rather than recommending you do more research.

Of the many definitions in Merriam Webster and others, I suggest the following are the relevant ones:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inroad)
> *inroad*:
> an advance or penetration often at the expense of someone or something —usually used in plural

> [filial](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/filial)
> *filial*:
> of, relating to, or befitting a son or daughter

> [free](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/free)
> *free*:
> relieved from or lacking something and especially something unpleasant or burdensome

original:
"... the pension ... would be freed from any little
filial inroads ..."

meaning:
"... the pension ... would be not have any little
demands made on it from a son or daughter ..."

or:
"... the pension ... would be not be reduced by using some of it to pay a little money to the son or daughter ..."

In this case it is the son, Henry, who is referred to. He will not need monetary help once he is married to the daughter of a man with plenty of money ("in easy circumstances").